# Three.js r89 memory leak with STL models

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I'm having a bit of trouble with a page I'm building. I think it's fairly simple, but I'm quickly running into issues from what I think is a memory leak.

First off, I've spent the majority of the day searching for an answer, so if I've missed something obvious I'm sorry, I promise I tried. Everything I've found has pointed me to the method I'm currently using, I'm at a loss now.

I have 30 STL models, all 120kb or less that I swap between. Only 3 are on screen at a time and the viewer can swap them out to customize the complete model.

I currently change the colors of the models using:

```
var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName(object);

newMaterial = '#'+matHex[newMaterial-1];
newMaterial = hexToRgb(newMaterial);

selectedObject.material.color = newMaterial;
```

That part works just fine and doesn't seem to slow anything down.

When it comes to replacing the model I use:

```
var mesh = scene.getObjectByName(object);

if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh)
{
    scene.remove(mesh);
    mesh.geometry.dispose();
    mesh.geometry = null;
    mesh.material.dispose();
    mesh.material = null;
    mesh = null;
}
```

After that I call a function that adds the model back into the scene:

```
function addHandle(){
    loader.load( stlPath+'Handle'+handleID+'.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    material = '0x'+matHex[handleMat-1]; //set color hex from array

    var handleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: parseInt(material), specular: specular, shininess: shininess } );
    var handleMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, handleMaterial );

    handleMesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    handleMesh.rotation.set( Math.PI/2, - Math.PI/2, 0 );
    handleMesh.scale.set( .008, .008, .008 );
    handleMesh.name = "Handle";
    handleMesh.id = handleID;
    handleMesh.castShadow = true;
    handleMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( handleMesh );

    updateHandle(); //check if Handle needs to rotate
    } );
}
```

From everything I have been able to find this is the proper method for disposing of meshes but after running through about a dozen of them the camera rotation starts to slow down, it takes slightly longer to load the next model, etc. It's especially noticeable on mobile devices.

Hopefully someone out there is able to notice something obvious that I'm missing, it would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Do your materials have textures? If so you may want to do something like `mesh.material.map.dispose()`. But with only ~4mb of models here, I'd have thought you could keep all of the models in memory and not even need to dispose them when swapping things out... in fact I would try that, and _not_ reload the model each time, or try destroying the loader between models in case it is caching things.

Comment: Currently the only thing I add to the models is the color, no textures. We didn't think it should cause a problem either but on an older phone (Samsung S4) it only takes a couple model updates before it starts to slow down the camera movement. One a computer I can reload several hundred times before it's noticeable.

I'll try destroying the loader and see if that helps. I'm using the same one to load everything so if it's caching that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem, and it was my fault like I suspected. I discovered that I was calling animate(); every time a model was replaced. After removing those it is running much much smoother. I'll report back if it ends up not being fixed!